# HTML form containing php send mail sending incomplete form email

Tags: php, email

Okay This is exactly my issue.
I have a html form which is on a page on my site. 
Then I have mail.php in the same directory.

The form sends the mail when submitting the form, that is not the problem, however it send an incomplete mail.

This is the html code

```
 <form name="contactform" form action="mail.php" method="post" 
class="w3_form_post">
            <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
                <div class="agileits_grid">
                    <h5>Name * </h5>
                    <div class="nam">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First 
Name" required="yes">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nam1">
                        <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Last 
Name" required="yes">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3_agileits_main_grid w3l_main_grid">
                <div class="agileits_grid">

                    <h5>Phone No: </h5>
                        <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="ex : 
082 123 4567" required="yes">

                </div>
                <div class="agileits_grid">
                    <h5>E-mail </h5>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ex : 
myname@gmail.com" required="no">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_grid w3ls_main_grid">
                <div class="agileinfo_grid">
                <h5>Preferred time to call</h5>

                    <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_gridl">
                        <input class="date" id="datepicker" name="date" 
type="text" value="mm/dd/yyyy" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if 
(this.value == '') {this.value = '08/13/2016';}" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_gridr">
                        <input type="time" name="time" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_grid w3ls_main_grid">

            </div>
            <div class="agileinfo_main_grid">

            </div>
            <div class="w3_main_grid">

                <div class="w3_main_grid_right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I am aware there is css references in there.
Also my page does have js on it.

This is the mail.php

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'equilibrium3.shaneel@gmail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Surname: ".$_POST["surname"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Date: ".$_POST["date"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Time to call: ".$_POST["time"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
\n\n

?>
```

And this is the response by email

```
Time to call: Email:
```

There is also no sender in the sender field.
I have entered all fields correctly when submitting the form.

Comment: $MESSAGE_BODY .= set this for all fields from surname not only last field

Comment: You forget to concat  $MESSAGE_BODY . Means put a .(dot) after $MESSAGE_BODY in each line

Answer (score 2):

```
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Surname: ".$_POST["surname"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Date: ".$_POST["date"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Time to call: ".$_POST["time"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";
```

Replace this code with

```
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Surname: ".$_POST["surname"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Date: ".$_POST["date"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Time to call: ".$_POST["time"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";
```